# How to turn off Google's page preview in search?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

How to turn off scripts in Google Search, in particular the page preview?

Comment: and your browser is!?

Comment: @MJH, Mozilla Firefox 3.6 with loads of extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind killing off all other Javascript features, the most reliable way is to just disallow all Javascript for the search page.

No thanks to Google using one domain for so many of its services, you can't do that with NoScript's base functionality, but you can with NoScript's ABE (Application Boundaries Enforcer) subsystem.

Here's a little ABE rule I wrote to kill Google Instant which also does what you want:

```
Site ^https://encrypted.google.com/(s|search)(\?.*|$)
Deny INC(SCRIPT,XHR)
Sandbox
```

Further details on this SuperUser answer I wrote earlier:

https://superuser.com/questions/260475/how-to-make-google-search-scriptless-with-noscript-adblock/325939#325939

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox Use Greasemonkey and this script http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/90222

Comment: Previews become screwed, but don't disappear and are still loaded when this script is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, you can use this snippet I came up with in your **userContent.css** file:

```
@-moz-document regexp("^https{0,1}://([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.){0,1}google\\..*") {
    .vspii, #nycp { display: none !important; }
    td#leftnav { display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: This will only hide it, not prent downloading/slowing things down, won't it?

Comment: Probably, depending on their exact implementation, which I don't care about at all because seeing it was what irritated me about it.

Comment: I mostly irritated by slowing down the browser even more and unnecessary traffic. Turned off scripts using NoScript's ABE and now it's OK.